# CPE exam: The children agreed to take it in turns to tidy the playroom

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, cambridge-exams

While preparing for the CPE exam I came across the following sentence transformation task:

> The children agreed they would each tidy the
>   playroom on alternate days.
>
> **turns**
>
> The children ________________________  the playroom.

My answer was:

> *The children agreed **to take turns tidying** the playroom.*

The key states:

> The children agreed **to take it in turns to** tidy the playroom.

Is my answer incorrect? If yes, then why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96984/discussion-on-question-by-elizabeth-banks-cpe-exam-the-children-agreed-to-take).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly, in British English you can take it in turns to do something, and you can take turns doing something too.

Both the stated answer and the Original Poster's answer are perfectly grammatical in British English. In fact,  the British National Corpus yields more hits for *take turns* than *take it in turns*, with 52 hits for the former and 31 hits for the latter (nothing much hinges on this). The BNC contains 100 million words.

However, the Corpus of American English, which contains about 520 million words, has 959 hits for *take turns* and zero hits for *take it in turns*.

To *take it in turns*, therefore, seems to be a very British phenomenon.

Comment: I personally think that even a British English speaker **would tend** to say: They took turns cleaning the floor. And not: They took **it** in turns **to clean the floor**. However, without the clean the floor both both AmE and BrE are the same: They took it in turns. However, I would agree with: They found it embarrassing to have to repeat their opinion several times.

Comment: @Lambie Well, I think I would say the *it* version but maybe write the *take turns* version. Colin also finds the *it* version completely natural.

Comment: You and he keep saying the it version: I find it difficult to understand your explanations. [OK for it]//But not: to take it in turns to [do something]. It simply does not sound right to my ear. Something to do with rhemes and themes. I have not yet worked it out to my own satisfaction.

Comment: Using *it* as Araucaria quotes seems fine to me (Brit), and indeed, more idiomatic.

Comment: @Lambie, as an American I will firmly state that we never say "take it in turns" as a part of our own dialect. When we need a phrase like this we say "take turns doing x". When we occasionally encounter "take it in turns", it is in a non-American source, and when we even more rarely use it, it is in imitation of other dialects (more specifically, Brits).

Comment: @wordsworth I'm sorry, I am an AmE speaker and "take it in turns" is not British sounding to me at all. But you and the others are still **missing my point**. My point was not about that but everybody seems to want to ignore it. But I am not going to repeat it again.

Comment: @Lambie Then you should post a question and clarify [why you said](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507018/cpe-exam-the-children-agreed-to-take-it-in-turns-to-tidy-the-playroom?noredirect=1#comment1227328_507018) *`Their answer [the key] is not grammatical: you can't have take it in turns and the playroom in my grammar book. `* and `You take turns doing x. or; You take it in turns. [no playroom].. `

Comment: That actually would make a good question, why is the pronoun "it" used in BrEng when the direct object has been mentioned.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because we don't like to use clauses as objects. So we tend to use *it* extrapositions when this occurs. The sentence means *We took to clean the room in turns*

Comment: Well, it would've made a good question.

Comment: @Araucaria "We took to clean the rooms in turn." is not grammatical. "We took to **cleaning** the rooms in turn." And that would be the same in AmE. He took to **brushing  his teeth** four times a day.

Comment: @Lambie You clearly didn't understand my description of that kind of extraposition.

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, I guess I don't understand agrammatical sentences purporting to explain usage. That is true.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not sure why you're protesting so much. In Araucaria's idiolect (and it seems many BrE speakers), the CPE key answer is grammatical. It works fine for them. I don't think it is up to you to say that it is not grammatical for them.

Comment: @Mitch My problem is not with the generic "take it in turns". My problem is with a double to-infinitive in that sentence. the **it** in **take it in turns** can easily be:  "The children agreed to take tidying the playroom [it] in turns." The double to-infinitive is extremely awkward regardless of the variety of English. Notice the silence of the honchos? We agreed to **take it in stride** to agree with everyone else? I think not.

Comment: @Lambie OK, I think you're referring to two infinitives in "The children agreed to take it in turns to tidy the playroom.". This is not how I would say it (AmE), but sounds fine to me, and whether it sounds fine to me (or you), it sounds fine to Araucaria and others, so it is grammatical for them. I don't see how you can say it's bad for them. You can totally say it doesn't work for you, but you can't say it doesn't work for them.

Comment: @Mitch I am not saying it is "bad for them". It often happens when someone disagrees with the collective (as I sometimes do), that others jump on the dissenter. Fine, Let's leave it at that, shall we?

Comment: @Lambie Sure, you can disagree with "leaving the it and adding a to-infinitive" (and expect it to be so for those you commonly speak with). But that's for _you_. It works fine for them. There's no one single English. You have one, and they have a (very slightly different) other.

Comment: @Mitch All I have seen are hits from corpora and opinions with no analysis. And one very odd dictionary entry. It is not I who needs a lesson in the non-singular nature of English, believe me.

Comment: @Lambie An absence of hits from corpora doesn't mean very much necessarily, but I'm afraid hits most certainly do. So do the grammaticality judgements of any significant number of native speakers ( when the results are positive). Apparently, you think you know what's grammatical in other varieties of English better than those speakers themselves. Well, that says a lot about your take on language in general. How about you do a googlebooks search? Then you could tell us which famous British authors can't speak English ;)

Comment: @Araucaria You are imputing things to me that I did not say or imply just because I do not agree with the opinions expressed by a few speakers here. Just because something is "found" in corpora, British or otherwise, does not explain its grammaticality or lack thereof. Stop moralizing. Stick to linguistic and other language-related arguments. I have every right to be an outlier without being harassed and insulted. Famous authors are famous authors, not grammarians and very often create realistic speech which may not or may not illustrate some point. Basta.

Comment: @Lambie But therein lies the rub. Grammar is the pattern that underlies all the things that speakers of the language do. Therefore, if a reasonable sample of speakers do something, it's grammatical. Q.E.D.

Comment: @Lambie Hasta pasta.

Comment: @Araucaria The apt comparison would be something like: take it in turns to [clean the playroom] **versus** take [cleaning the playroom] in turns. Then, one might be getting somewhere collocation-wise. The OED has only two sentences with "take it in turns to" and both are 19th century. And I can't search for the other one with take [x] in turns.